# Sequelize migrations - Unable to change reference on column

Tags: sql-server, sequelize.js, database-migration, sequelize-cli

My database is MSSQL.

I have a migration script where I have created the table like this:

```
module.exports = {
    up: function(queryInterface) {
        return queryInterface.createTable(
            'tablename', {
                'column1': {
                    type: SEQUELIZE.INTEGER,
                    references: {
                        model: 'Foobar',
                        key: 'id',
                        onDelete: 'cascade'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

I want to change the reference for this column, so I wrote another migration script:

```
module.exports = {
    up: function(queryInterface) {
        return queryInterface.changeColumn(
            'tablename', {
                'column1': {
                    type: SEQUELIZE.INTEGER,
                    references: {
                        model: 'BarFoo', //I changed the reference
                        key: 'id',
                        onDelete: 'cascade'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

However, on running the migration, I find that the reference is not changed in the database. The column still refers to the old reference - `FooBar` instead of `BarFoo`. The migration script ran successfully but the change did not happen. Any idea why?

I run the migrations using sequelize cli - `sequelize db:migrate`